# Non-parallel, awaited Async calls in Entity Framework Core lead to InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, entity-framework, async-await, entity-framework-core

Working in a codebase using EF Core 5 on a Web API project with a Dependency Injected, Scoped EF Repository.

The code has worked well with Asynchronous queries (all `await`ed), but I noticed the calls to `SaveChanges()` were **not** async.  A predecessor implemented `SaveChanges()` via a `Commit()` method in the base repository class (see below).

After switching the `SaveChanges()` calls to `SaveChangesAsync()` via `CommitAsync()` in the base repository, even though these calls **do** `await` their completion and *no other threads should be using the Scoped repository* (not spinning up any Tasks, etc.) and all preceding calls to the repository / `DbContext` are being `await`ed, we are still getting this exception:

> A second operation was started on this context before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads concurrently using the same instance of DbContext. For more information on how to avoid threading issues with DbContext, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2097913.

I've spent hours on this now. We're not breaking any of the rules as per above.  It makes no sense...

Here is our context-adding code in Startup - note, this is by default a request Scoped service:

```
services.AddDbContext<DbReadWriteContext>(
      options => options.UseSqlServer(sqlReadWriteConnectionString,
            providerOptions => providerOptions.UseNetTopologySuite().EnableRetryOnFailure(
                  maxRetryCount: 10,
                  maxRetryDelay: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
                  errorNumbersToAdd: null
            )));
```

Here is our Repository adding code in Startup - note these are also request Scoped:

```
services.AddScoped<ICompanyRepository, CompanyRepository>();
services.AddScoped<IAppointmentRepository, AppointmentRepository>();
```

Our Repositories inherit from a base repository which implements some 'helper' methods, including these two in question:

```
public IQueryable<T> GetQuery()
{
   return _context.Set<T>();
}

public Task<T> GetSingleAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
   return _context.Set<T>().FirstOrDefaultAsync(predicate);
}

// Existing
public virtual int Commit()
{
   return _context.SaveChanges();
}

// Newly added
public virtual Task<int> CommitAsync()
{
   return _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

And here is an example of code that fails with the above exception:

```
var appointment = await _appointmentRepository.GetQuery().Where(a => a.Id == appointmentId)
    .Include(b => b.Business)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

var company = await _companyRepository.GetSingleAsync(c => c.Id == companyId);

if (company.SendNotice == true)
{
   appointment.NoticeSent = true;
   _appointmentRepository.Update(appointment);
   await _appointmentRepository.CommitAsync();
}
```

There is simply no reason I see why we should be receiving this exception.

Comment: Have you considered spinning up a new context for each unit of work?

Comment: I have noticed that same exception may appear if you have `async void` method in call sequence.

Comment: The problem somwhere upper in the call tree. Make sure you are not missing `await`, there is no `async void` and no `ids.Select(id => Do(id))`. When your method was sync the Select worked sequentially, but when it was converted to async, it started to run concurrently.

Comment: @Enigmativity thanks for the thought - By swapping controller-wide DI of Repositories/context, moving those to endpoint-locally scoped context, the issue has gone away, but it would be nice to discover what was causing it in the first place.

Comment: @Artur and Syvatoslav thank you for your responses. No `async void` anywhere.  No parallel Tasks.  No delegate loops like `ids.Select(id => Do(id))`.

Comment: Do you have [EF Core Interceptors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/interceptors) in your codebase?

Comment: @Artur no, we do not.

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of others experiencing the same issue, we resolved this by replacing controller-wide Dependency Injection (DI) of Repositories/context with a DbContext within each controller endpoint, instantiated via the DI Service Provider.